# How to get the code to print out Usernames that are between 5 and 10 characters long?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I have this code to print all of the usernames in the /etc/passwd file however i am trying to get the code to only print out usernames that are between 5 and 10 characters long does anyone know how i would do this?

```
#!/bin/bash

MAXLENGTH=$(cut -d: -f1 < /etc/passwd | wc -L)
MINLENGTH=$MAXLENGTH
SMALLESTNAME=""

for NAME in $(cut -d: -f1 < /etc/passwd)
do
if [ ${#NAME} -eq $MAXLENGTH ]
    then
            echo "The Longest UserName In The System 
Is:" $NAME
            echo " Its Length Is" $MAXLENGTH
    elif [ ${#NAME} -lt $MINLENGTH ]
    then
            MINLENGTH=${#NAME}
            SMALLESTNAME=$NAME
    fi

 done

 echo
 echo "The Smallest UserName In The System Is:" 
 $SMALLESTNAME
 echo "Its Length is:" $MINLENGTH
```

Comment: Reading the file twice is inefficient. You could easily avoid the `wc -L` and just update the max as you go through the file.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F : '/^[^:]{5,10}:/ { print $1 }' /etc/passwd
```

The regular expression looks for 5-10 characters which are not the field separator at the beginning of line, followed by the field separator. (Otherwise, without the requirement to end with the field separator, we would also capture strings with more than 10 characters before the field separator.)

Here is an Awk replacement for your shell script attempt.

```
awk -F : 'NR==1 {
        min = max = length($1)
        longest = shortest = $1
        next }
    { len = length($1) }
    len < min {
        shortest = $1
        min = len }
    len > max {
        longest = $1
        max = len }
    END {
        print "Longest " longest " (" max ")"
        print "Shortest " shortest " (" min ")" }' /etc/passwd
```

Like your original attempt, this will obviously print incomplete results in the (likely) event that more than one entry has the same length as the selected longest or shortest element. It would not be too hard to collect the elements of the same length into, say, a colon-separated string, and start over if we find a new longest or shortest element.

Comment: This does not work, nothing prints when the program is executed

Comment: this may be because i placed it in a bash file as that is what i need

Answer (score 0):

You can determine the length of a bash string using ${#var}.

For example,

```
VARIABLE=hello
echo "$VARIABLE has ${#VARIABLE} characters."
```

Comment: I understand that however i only want the program to print usernames that are between 5 and ten characters long how would i do that?

Comment: How exactly are you finding this hard to apply?